# Merging small polygons

Tags: polygon, shapely

I have a situation where I'm getting small polygons in the data I'm receiving and I would like to merge these using Shapely so that they would be combined with the larger ones. Here is an example of what I'm talking about. [image]

The image is generated from Shapely's `GeometryCollection` using just `polygons.svg()`. Using `cascaded_union` seems to merge the small polygons, but the problem is that after that all the walls are just merged and I'm left with this single polygon which is not what I'm looking for.

How could this be achieved?

Comment: So you want to merge the polygons, but aren't happy that the outcome is a single polygon? I think you need to clarify your expected outcome.

Comment: Yes. I want to merge the small polygons that you see appearing in the corners to the larger ones, but not to merge all the large polygons. So I assume given some threshold for the area of the polygon it should be merged.

Comment: How can you determine _which_ larger polygons will "receive" the smaller polygons?

Comment: I agree with @alphabetasoup you need to explain your rules. Take bottom right square, why should it merge into the left polygon instead of the above? Until you explicitly define your ruleset this is unsolvable.